# Type promotion and conversion in c

Tags: c++, c, variables, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

```
double dVal;
int iVal = -7;
unsigned long ulVal = 1000;
dVal = iVal * ulVal;
printf("iVal * ulVal = %lf\n", dVal);
```

Can someone explain step by step how to get 4294960296.000000?

- What comes first, changing the sign of iVal to unsigned or promotion
  to ulVal type before multiplication with ulVal?
- Also if we multiplicate iVal and ulVal we are out of range for long type
  and we store that value of multiplication to double variable (so we have conversion
  again). But how we can know to which value to round, when double type
  is the most precise around 0 and as far we go from 0 the distance
  between adjacent numbers is bigger?

Comment: [This implicit conversions reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) might come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really quite simple:

iVal is promoted from int to unsigned long. So its value of -7 (being a two's compliment) becomes a positive value of 0xFFFFFFF9 (ie. 4294967289) (at least on your particular system).

This when multipled by 1000 overflows the unsigned long, so instead of being a result of 4,294,967,289,000 (0x3E7 FFFF E4A8) it ends up 0xFFFFE4A8 (429960296).

This is then converted to a double, getting your final answer. The trailing zeros are because the value of the float is very slightly above 429960296 because it is constructed as a sum of fractions that printf is rounding to 6 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion as mentioned by Joachim,

First the multiplication of the two integers occurs. The result is then stored in the float.

So we look at `iVal * ulVal`. Here we refer to the section on **Usual arithmetic conversions**. Both operands are integers so case 4. applies.

First the **integer Promotions** occur. In this, both operands are ints or greater so they are unchanged.

> If the types after promotion are the same, that type is the common type

This is not applicable, as the types are int and unsigned long respectively.

> Otherwise, if both operands after promotion have the same signedness (both signed or both unsigned), the operand with the lesser conversion rank (see below) is implicitly converted to the type of the operand with the greater conversion rank

This too, does not apply, as one type is signed and the second is unsigned

> Otherwise, the signedness is different: If the operand with the unsigned type has conversion rank greater or equal than the rank of the type of the signed operand, then the operand with the signed type is implicitly converted to the unsigned type

Here the unsigned operand is long and the signed is int, The rank for long is greater than int, so this part applies. The signed int is converted to a unsigned long.

So, we have the multiplication of two numbers `4294967289` (unsigned long) and `1000` (unsigned long). Doing the multiplication there is an overflow but if you calculate `4294967289000 % 2^32`, you get `4294960296`.

This is then converted to a float at the equality sign and then printed.